# How to check iceconnectionstate in peerjs

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

how to know the "iceconnectionstate" is changed?

this is what i'm doing

```
conn.on("iceconnectionstatechange",function (){
 alert("state changed");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
conn.peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
    const iceConnState = conn.peerConnection.iceConnectionState
    alert(iceConnState)
}
```

This is listening to an ice connection state change. On each change you can get the current state and prompt an alert.